# Android 13 folder access

Tags: java, android

My app needs access to a folder in order to work, it needs to access files and create files in that folder. I saw this in some console emulators, the file manager opened, after selecting a folder, I received a request for access to this folder. How to implement this, I can not find the answer for a long time.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted, so request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    225);
        } else {
            // Permission is already granted, so proceed
            selectFolder();
        }
```

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        /*if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 1) {//>0
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    this.finish();
                }
            }
        }*/

        if (requestCode == 225) {
            // Check if the user has granted permission
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted, so proceed
                selectFolder();
            } else {
                // Permission is not granted, so display a message to the user
                //Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private void selectFolder() {
        // Get a file chooser dialog to allow the user to select a folder
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
    }
```

this code was suggested to me by google Bard,
but it doesn't work, the request doesn't come, nothing happens, this code worked to import the file only via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

As I understand it, I need to use SAF, but only media files can be accessed there, but i need other files as well (.obj, .atlas, .pack, .pfx)

i know about permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but there will be problems with it when publishing the application

tried what suggested by google Bard

```
File publicFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File newFolder = new File(publicFolder, "my_public_folder");
newFolder.mkdirs();
```

but I did not find the required request, and the program crashes on this

Answer (score 0):

**The Android folder is supposed to be inaccessible in Android 11 and newer. Due to a bug, workarounds worked until Android 13 got released. Only access on the device itself is blocked. You can access the folder just fine if you connect your device to a computer.**

Answer (score -1):

**Android 13 - access the media folder**

*please provide permission in manifest file "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", access to file directory then used "READ_MEDIA_IMAGES", "READ_MEDIA_VIDEO", "READ_MEDIA_AUDIO". if you want to access media files in other apps' directories.*

*"getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()" used this method for shared storage directory.*

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String path = "";
    if (getContentResolver() != null) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}

File file = new File("/path/to/file");
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(bytes);
            String contents = new String(bytes);
            Log.d("TAG", "Contents: " + contents);
```

**try this line in input stream**

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("my_obj_file.obj");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Do something with the line.
            }
            Resources resources = getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.my_atlas_file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               
            }
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my_pack_file.pack";
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               
            }
```

Comment: again, this method gives access to media files (images, video and audio) but I need other types of files

Comment: which type sir, please suggest.

Comment: I hope , above code usable

Comment: I didn’t quite understand how to select a folder through the file manager through this code and call up a window asking for access to this folder, can you explain in more detail

Comment: if you provide permission notification for android 13 and above  then provide permission in manifest file "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />" and used this line  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
        }